# Prevent Div from moving

Tags: html, css

I am working with a website with css drop down menus within the header div. When the drop down menu appears it resizes the header div therefore shoving down the content div.

In the body of my index.php:

```
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="container">
<?php include_once("header.php"); ?>
<div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

The header.php

```
<div class="header">
<div style="display: table-cell; width: 250px; text-align: center;">
LOGO
</div>
<div style="display: table-cell;">
<br><br><br>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 6</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 7</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

And main.css

```
ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #333;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background: #939393;
}
ul li ul{
    display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul{
    display: block; /* display the dropdown */
}
.top{
    background: #1b2d3c;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
.container{
    width: 1100px;
    height: 1000px;
}
.header{
    display: table-row;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 130px;
}
.content{
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 500px;
}
* {
    background: #87a0b4;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
}
```

I apologize for the lengthy post. How can I prevent the problem I am having? I want to be sure I am doing things correctly before I get too deep into the project.

Comment: You want to position your sub-menues absolutely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change `position` of `ul li:hover ul` to `absolute`, and add some other properties like this [JSFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/82r9m/embedded/result/) ([Source](http://jsfiddle.net/82r9m/))

```
ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Hope this will help you ..

Comment: Works beautifully thank you! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

As was said in the previous answer, you need to set `position: absolute`. I'd like to add a bit of information as to why.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning):

> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in the normal flow of elements in the document. In contrast, an element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes up no space when placing other elements. The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor. If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial container is used.

Basically, by giving an element absolute positioning, it is no longer being taken into account when positioning the rest of the page. It will take up its alloted space in its set position no matter what.

In your case, the div was moving relative to the elements surrounding it. By using `position: absolute`, you are ommiting and relativity.